# Will quantum computers ever work?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-computer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do some physicists believe that scalable quantum computing is possible?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35218/why-do-some-physicists-believe-that-scalable-quantum-computing-is-possible)

The idea of a [quantum computer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_computer) is that a quantum system can be in a [Quantum Superposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_superposition) of many states.
then the same calculation can be done on each of the states of the superposition, so the system can do many calculations in parallel.
This idea leads to the possibility of much more powerful computers than would be possible with ordinary processors.

Comment: I don't think that's the idea. Classical linear systems also have superposition principle. What they don't have is entanglement. That's what gives the q.computer an edge in some situations.

Comment: @MBN quantum computing is look like painting on water!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/35218/2451

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are [working quantum computers](http://www.dwavesys.com/en/products-services.html) right now.

Comment: Except that it is very likely that what they have is a fancy very expensive special purpose classical computer.

Comment: @MBN That's very unlikely. I can't imagine why would they create such sophisticated hoax.

Comment: Well, they admit that their computer cannot run Shor's algorithm. What I would call a quantum computer should be able to do that.